# Multiple installs Installshield 2010

Tags: installshield, installshield-2011

I'm trying to create an installation and ask the user within my installer if they want to install two additional programs using check boxes. The installer should then start the installation based on the value of the check box.

I'm having trouble including the separate installations with mine. One is an .msi file and the other is an .exe file. I am able to include them as prerequisites and have the user optionally install them; however, when they are launched from my installer, they are hidden behind my installer window.

I have tried adding them as custom actions but I am unable to get them to launch. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding them as prerequisites is the correct approach.

The fact that their windows are shown behind your installer is actually a limitation in Windows. Starting with Vista windows are no longer shown on top by default to prevent spamming the user with popups. Instead, they are shown in the background and their taskbar button flashes.

So there's not much you can do. The only approach I would recommend is to try some other setup authoring tools and see if you can find one which doesn't behave this way. Some bootstrappers use special code which bring the prerequisite windows on top.